# calling a non abstact class method in abstract class

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

i am calling a method from a class to abstract class but the mothod is not working. it's not giving any error or crashing.
here is some code from the abstract class where i'm calling method of another class

```
     this.iv_done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v(TAG, "done the view");
            edit_activity.done();
    }
    });
```

and here is done() method which i am calling from edit_activity class.

```
  public void done(){
    if (a == 1) {
        iv_sticker.setEnabled(false);
        iv_sticker.removeborder();
    } else if (a == 2) {
        iv_moonch.setEnabled(false);
        iv_moonch.removeborder();
    }

}
```

I couldn't find any problem in my code or crashing plz tell me if there is any mistake in my code or something more to add. thanks

Comment: Please follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) so it is clearer what these variables (or classes, as they may be) are.

Answer (score -1):

Make done() static is wrong because your iv_sticker and iv_moonch is non-static, so the right way is set/new your edit_activity instance into your OnClickListener.